# Can't access my flask app running on my virtual machine

Tags: windows, ubuntu, flask, virtualbox

I'm running a Ubuntu 18.10 LTS virtual box on my Windows 10 system.
In the network configuration I set the network to `bridge`.
After that my virtual machine appears in my local network with the ip `192.168.0.231`.
A `ping` from my hosting system to the VM works fine.

I'm then starting a flask app with `DEBUG=TRUE, TEST=TRUE, SERVER_NAME=127.0.0.1:5001`. On the VM the server starts and is available under localhost:5001.

But from my hosting service I get `Could not get any response`, when I try to access `192.168.0.231:5001`.

Do I have to open some ports on the VM?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

- Start the VM with the port forwarded and be sure it is not used on your Host OS
- use when starting the app `--host=0.0.0.0` if you start it with `flask run`